# update UI from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I created a custom `TextView` to show and images on it. I have to download the images and then show them on the `textview`. So I thought that I can do my job with a `AsyncTask` class. On the `doInBackground` I download and save the image on the Internal storage (for offline mode), and on the `onPostExecute` I call a method which shows the images on the `textview`. But it doesn't work. I mean instead of showing the images it shows the `img` tags.

I also tried to get the status from the `AsyncTask` class on the `onPostExecute` method and it's `RUNNING`. Isn't that weird? I thought that it will be `FINISHED`. Am I missing something about AsyncTask class?

Below is `addImages` method, where I find the `img` tags from the text and store the data on a `List`, and call the `DownLoadImage` class which extends the `AsyncTask`.

```
 private boolean add(final Context context, final Spannable spannable) {
    path = context.getFilesDir();

    Pattern refImgPattern = Pattern.compile("<img .+?\\/>");
    hasChanges = false;

    refImgMatcher = refImgPattern.matcher(spannable);
    while (refImgMatcher.find()) {

    set = true;
    for (ImageSpan span : spannable.getSpans(refImgMatcher.start(), refImgMatcher.end(), ImageSpan.class)) {
            if (spannable.getSpanStart(span) >= refImgMatcher.start()
                        && spannable.getSpanEnd(span) <= refImgMatcher.end()
                        ) {
                spannable.removeSpan(span);
             } else {
               set = false;
               break;
              }
          }

    String imageUrl = spannable.subSequence(refImgMatcher.start(0), refImgMatcher.end(0)).toString().trim();

    width = 0;
    Pattern widthPattern = Pattern.compile("width=\"[0-9]+?\"");
    Matcher widthMatcher = widthPattern.matcher(imageUrl);

        if (widthMatcher.find()) {
            String w = widthMatcher.group(0);
            w = w.replaceAll("width=", "");
            w = w.replaceAll("\"", "");
            width = Integer.valueOf(w);
        }

            height = 0;
            Pattern heightPattern = Pattern.compile("height=\"[0-9]+?\"");
            Matcher heightMatcher = heightPattern.matcher(imageUrl);

            if (heightMatcher.find()) {
                String h = heightMatcher.group(0);
                h = h.replaceAll("height=", "");
                h = h.replaceAll("\"", "");
                height = Integer.valueOf(h);
            }

     Pattern urlPattern = Pattern.compile("(http|ftp|https):\\/\\/([\\w_-]+(?:(?:\\.[\\w_ -]+)+))([\\w.,@?^=%&:\\/~+#-]*[\\w@?^=%&\\/~+#-])?");
     Matcher urlMatcher = urlPattern.matcher(imageUrl);

        if (urlMatcher.find())
            imageUrl = urlMatcher.group(0);

            imageName = siteData.getId() + "_" + imageUrl.substring(imageUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, imageUrl.length());

            images.add(new Image(imageUrl, imageName, width, height, refImgMatcher.start(0), refImgMatcher.end(0)));


    }

    if (images.size() > 0) {

        for (final Image img : images) {
            image = new File(path, img.name);
            if (!image.exists()) {
            new DownLoadImage(context, spannable, img).execute();
            } else
                addImages(spannable, context, img);
        }
    }

    return hasChanges;
 }
```

This is the `addImages` method where I replace the tags with images

```
 private void addImages(Spannable spannable, Context context, Image im) {
        image = new File(path, im.name);
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);
        if (im.width > 0 && im.height > 0)
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, im.width * 3, im.height * 3, true);

        if (set) {
            hasChanges = true;
            spannable.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, bitmap),
                    im.startIndex,
                    im.endIndex,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
            );
        }

    }
```

and the `DownLoadImage` class

```
private class DownLoadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private Connection connection = Connection.getInstance();
        private Context context;
        private Spannable spannable;
        private Image image;

        public DownLoadImage(Context context, Spannable spannable, Image image) {
            this.spannable = spannable;
            this.context = context;
            this.image = image;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                connection.openConnection(image.path, ConnectionType.GET, false, false, null);

                Integer status = connection.getResponseCode();
                if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
                    InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    Actions.saveImage(context, bitmap, image.name);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                connection.closeConnection();
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            Log.i("status", this.getStatus().toString());
            addImages(spannable, context, image);
        }
    }
```

***** EDIT *****

the `getTextWithImages` where I call the `add` method

```
private Spannable getTextWithImages(Context context, CharSequence text) {
    images = new ArrayList<>();

    Spannable spannable = spannableFactory.newSpannable(text);
    add(context, spannable);
    return spannable;
}
```

and the `setText` method where I call the `getTextWithImages`

```
@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    Spannable s = getTextWithImages(getContext(), text);
    super.setText(s, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

Comment: 1. Check that your regex is correct. 2. Just parse the image URL and let [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) do the rest.

Comment: the regex is correct because it work's for the offline mode. I tried with Picasso to, but the output was the same

Comment: Does the regex get you a valid URL? If you go to that URL on a browser, does it show the picture?

Comment: yes the download works. But I can show the on the textview only when the photos are already on the storage. The problem is when I download them and then try to show them

Comment: Do you have the `INTERNET` permission in your manifest?

Comment: yes I have INTERNET permission. and WRITE and READ.

Comment: Where is your `addImages()` method in your `DownloadImage` class?  If i'm not mistaken, this should throw an exception in the execution of the AsyncTask (DownloadImage).

Comment: it's in the onPostExecute method...no it doesn't throw a exception....I believe that the problem is that I try to update the UI before the thread end the task...but this isn't the onPostExecute's job? to begin when the thread ends?

Comment: Yes, that's what `onPostExecute()` is for. I don't think you would see the exception unless you were debugging it, since it's in a background thread. Both your `addImages()` methods are private, so I wasn't quite sure how you were calling the methods from your AsyncTask. Hmm okay, where is the `private void addImages(Spannable spannable, Context context, Image im) {` method located? Is it in the activity?

Comment: no it's in the custom TextView class...if you want to call the method on the UI thread, the problem is when I tried to cast the context to AppCompatActivity it throws a ClassCastException, that I can't cast ContextThemeWrapper to AppCompatActivity...and when I tried to make a setter to get the context from the fragment where I have this custom textview it throws inflate exception

Answer (score 0):

You could create an interface that invokes a callback to the UI thread, instead of using the context.  For example, in your AsyncTask:

```
private class DownLoadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private Connection connection = Connection.getInstance();
    private Context context;
    private Spannable spannable;
    private Image image;
    private OnImageDownloadedListener mOnImageDownloadedListener;
    ...

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ...
        ...
    }
    // Interface the task will use to communicate with your activity method.
    public interface OnImageDownloadedListener {
        void onImageDownloaded(Spannable spannable, Image image); // No need for context.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        if (mOnImageDownloadedListener != null) {
            // If we set a listener, invoke it.
            mOnImageDownloadedListener.onImageDownloaded(spannable, image);
        }
    }

    // Setter.
    public setOnImageDownloadedListener(OnImageDownloadedListener listener) {
        mOnImageDownloadedListener = listener;
    }
}
```

Then when you create your task try:

```
if (!image.exists()) {
    // Create the task.
    DownloadImage downloadTask = new DownLoadImage(context, spannable, img);

    // Set your listener.
    downloadTask.setOnImageDownloadedListener(new OnImageLoadedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageDownloaded(Spannable spannable, Image image) {
            // Add the images.
            addImages(spannable, **YourContextHere(Activity/etc)**.this, image)
        }
    });

    // Execute.
    downloadTask.execute();
} else
    addImages(spannable, context, img);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: no it has the same output. :\
Look, I debug the app and found that when I download the images and go to show them the hasChanges value (the value that returns the add method) is false, but when I try to show them from the internal storage is true...

Comment: hasChanges will always be false from the download task, because the AsyncTask is asynchronous. When you call `execute()` a background thread, that is separate from the UI thread, is created and in that background thread, `doInBackground()` is executed. `execute()` is non-blocking, meaning it will run, then continue on to the next line of code immediately, whether or not the code in `doInBackground()` is finished or not.

Comment: hmmm, so how can I make the add method return true? :\

Comment: Well, the short answer is, you can't, when you have to download the image.  You have to write your logic to account for the downloading process to finish, which you can do using a listener `interface` like the one I posted in my answer.  It's hard to explain as we don't have any idea of how you are using the `add()` method.

Comment: In my 2nd code block, when setting the listener, that code will be run when the background process is finished (whether or not the download succeeded or not is still up to you to figure out in `doInBackground()`), so when `addImages()` is called in the listener, it's 100% guaranteed that the `DownloadImage` task has finished.

Comment: So if you implemented this code correctly, you can definitely rule out the possibility that it is trying to display your image before the download task has finished. If it's still not working, it's most likely a different issue and we would need more information.

Comment: first of all, about the add method, you are true, so I updated the question with the method where I call the add method. About new comment, yes I know that it must call the listener when the task has finished, but the status says RUNNING, not FINISHED

Comment: I think the status is RUNNING because it's the status of the AsyncTask, not the `doInBackground()` method, so technically, your AsyncTask is still RUNNING in `onPostExecute()`. Once `onPostExecute()` has finished, it should say FINISHED